# Materialize.css inserir icon por cima de uma imagem do card

Tags: css, css3, materialize

Olá,
Tenho alguns cards em materialize.css que gostava de inserir por cima da imagem (.card-image) um icon especifico (no exemplo o icon de video), mas não estou a conseguir.

```
<div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" v-if="impar(index)">
                <img class="responsive-img" data-target="modal-{{noticia.id}}" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)"
                     :src="'storage/noticias/images/' + noticia.photo"
                     :class="{'activator': noticia.videoValue}"/>
                <div v-if="noticia.videoValue == false" class="video-icon-noticias valign-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" data-target="modal-{{noticia.id}}"  class="playIcon" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)">
                        <i class="large material-icons">play_circle_outline</i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Já tentei de várias maneiras mas não consegui.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorância minha. Está documentado na documentação do materialize que é possivel adicionar um titulo à image-card.
Embora ainda não tenha conseguido centrar o icon ele já aparece sobre a imagem.
Segue o código:

```
<div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light valign-wrapper" v-if="impar(index)">
                <img class="responsive-img" data-target="modal-{{noticia.id}}" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)"
                     :src="'storage/noticias/images/' + noticia.photo"
                     :class="{'activator': noticia.videoValue}"/>
                <span class="card-title center">
                    <div v-if="noticia.videoValue == false" class="video-icon-noticias valign center-block">
                        <a href="#" data-target="modal-{{noticia.id}}" class="playIcon" @click.prevent.sync="openModal(noticia.id)">
                            <i class="large material-icons">play_circle_outline</i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
```